# Send form url without JS

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a form sending some vars by JS

```
<form id="custemail" action="mail/out.php" method="post">
    ....
    <input type="submit" value="Create & Send">
</form>
```

I need to change post URl on php side. How must i change my Js code so it'll work. I mean I don't want to use url:"mail/out.php", in my JS. 
Or I can use If else on JS side. But the vars coming from php. So I don't know how to use them. I have 8 different conditions.

The JS code:

```
$('#sending').click(function(){
            $.prompt("What is customer's email?","",
            function(value){        

                $.ajax({
                url: "mail/out.php",
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#custemail').serialize(),
                } ).done (function(data) {
                    $.msg("Message sent to the '"+value+"'?");
              });

            },
            function(){
                $.msg("You clicked cancel!");
            });
        });
```

Comment: can we see the out.php file? I am not exactly sure what part you need help on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ajaxSubmit()](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) so the JS grabs the url from the action attribute of the form.

You could also grab it yourself with something like:

`var url = $("#custemail").attr("action");`

The code above will return anything that the action attribute of the form contains, so you'd just have to do "url: url" on the $.ajax call.

I think the second option is much better, since it doesn't require an entire plugin to do it, but the plugin which includes ajaxSubmit is pretty nice and worth checking out.

Comment: worked like;

 var url = $("#formmail").attr("action");
                    $.ajax({
      url: ''+url+'',
                    type: 'POST',

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Javascript is being created by a PHP script, you would do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo $url; ?>",
    ...
});
```

Comment: That's assuming a bit too much.

Comment: I don't think that's too much to assume considering the level of the OP. This looks like a trivial issue and echoing php vars in an inline js script is very common. I trust barmar to post sane answers